# In Revelation12:14, the word "times", could it mean more than two?

Tags: revelation

Could time's be more than two time's, in a time time's and half a time.
You could say Jesus lived for a time times and half a time, the time's is 8 time's
1260 days to 0 BC and 8 time's 1260 is 28 years plus 1 year and 3/4 thats about 33 1/3 years?? its a thought?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for the question.  Please remember to take the tour below to best understand how this site works.

Comment: its 8 times, we already know Daniel was speaking on the future not the present

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day-year_principle

Comment: I will Quote the Naqshbandi Prophet Abu Yaqub Yusaf al hamadani ( Just because you are not privy to the secrets, Do you think know one else is either) Your all stuck in the past thats why you can't see whats right in front of you, I will not post herte again

Answer (score 1):

No. It is a Greek translation of the Hebrew dual, meaning two. It is a reference to the same phrase in Daniel 7.25 and 12.7, which is described as a half-week of years in Dan 9.27.

If you have a perfect religious calendar, then it also equals 42 months and 1,260 days. These times period occur several times in Rev 11 and 12 (referring to the same time, but exploring different aspects of it) but only in these chapters.

It signifies the 'in-between' time in which we live. It is the time between Jesus' first coming and his return, when the kingdom of God (the 'age to come') has broken in, but this age is still all around us. It is the time when Christians experience our Exodus 'desert wandering' since we have left the slavery of sin in spiritual 'Egypt' but have not yet entered the promised land of the New Jerusalem.

(The numbers 42 and 1,260 are also 'rectangular' numbers which share some qualities of square numbers, which signify God, and triangular numbers, which signify evil. We are to be God's holy people in a fallen world.)

Comment: Considering that Ian gave the acceptable answer I'll add that Revelation speaks of the 3.5 years following the crucifixion event. Referencing the same event twice, during which St John took care of Mary. Rev 12:2 defines the timing as the first coming, seeing as how the second coming he returns from the sky as referenced in Acts.

Comment: But in Revelation all these time periods are symbolic, not literal. I don't believe that Revelation and the Fourth gospel were written by the same person (there are too many differences in language).

Answer (score 0):

No.  A time was 1 year; times was 2 years; and half a time was 1/2 year.  Three and 1/2 years.  This is the same as 42 months, or 1260 days (30 days/mo).  The problem comes in trying to use the book of Revelation as a still future prophesy.  It must be read in perspective of the first audience, which was of the saints to whom it was sent in the 1st century AD!

Revelation was written before the destruction of Jerusalem approximately 66 - 68 AD.  We have confirmation brought forth by Robert Young in his concordance (Young’s Analytical Concordance, 1885) concerning the date of the writing of Revelation:

> “It was written in Patmos about A.D. 68, whither John had been banished by Domitius Nero, as stated in the title of the Syria version of the book; and with this concurs the express statement of Irenaeus in A.D. 175, who says it happened in the reign of Domitianou – i.e., Domitius (Nero).  Sulpicius, Orosius, etc., stupidly mistaking Domitianou for Domitianikos, supposed Irenaeus to refer to Domitian, A.D. 95, and most succeeding writers have fallen into the same blunder.  The internal testimony is wholly in favor of the early date. The temple at Jerusalem was still standing (ch. 11.1-10); the exact duration of the siege is foretold, viz., 42 months, 3(-)1/2 years, or 1260 days; the two witnesses are to be slain in the city where our Lord was crucified; Nero was reigning at the time, for it is said of the seven kings of Rome; ‘five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come, and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.’ The five kings are Julius Caesar, Augustus, Tiberius, Caligula, Claudius. The ‘one who is ‘ is Nero; the one who ‘must continue for a short space’ is Galba, who reigned only seven months. Everywhere the events are ‘to come quickly,’ lit. ‘with haste,’ or speed (ch. 1.1; 2.16; 3.11; 11.14; 22.7, 12, 20). The escape of the Christian Jews from Jerusalem to Pella is undoubtedly referred to in ch. 7.1-8, compared with Mat. 24.30.’”  (1)

The prophesy of Revelation was the fulfillment of the original prophesy Gabriel gave to Daniel in Dan. ch. 9 - 12, which detailed the people and the city of this prophesy.

> *"Seventy weeks are determined **upon thy people** and upon **thy holy city**, to finish the transgression, and to make an end of sins, and to make reconciliation for iniquity, and to bring in everlasting righteousness, and to seal up the vision and prophecy, and to anoint the most Holy."*  (Dan. 9:24, KJV)

When left in the context of the words Gabriel spoke to Daniel, "thy people" was Daniel's people, and "thy holy city" was Daniel's holy city - the Jews and Jerusalem.  Daniel's people were not the Russians, nor the Germans, nor the French, nor the Iranians, nor the Americans, nor the Chinese.  The entire prophesy was of the full and complete destruction of Jerusalem and that second temple they built after the return from the Babylonian captivity.

The Messiah would be cut off in the middle of the 70th week (of 7 years).  Bypassing for the moment the argument over when the command was given to rebuild the temple, we can positively identify the time period when the Messiah was cut off - 31 (33) AD - the first century AD.  Just focusing on the time of the 70th week we can know several things.

The middle of that 70th week meant that 3-1/2 years of that week had already passed, and they were the 3-1/2 years of Jesus' ministry on earth.  Cutting Him off in the middle of that week was His crucifixion.  First century AD.

The last 3-1/2 years happened after the preaching of the gospel throughout the known world, the inhabited world of that century... the same world of the Roman empire which was defined in Luke 2:1. (2)  Paul testified in Col. 1:23:

> *"...the hope of the gospel, which ye have heard, and which was preached to every creature which is under heaven; ..."*  (KJV)

Every creature under heaven was the reference to every soul under the authority and dominion of that Roman empire of the 1st century AD.  The word "heaven" was used in OT prophesies as a metaphor for earthly kingdoms - dominions and authority of men as a type, a small piece of God's entire heaven over all the earth.  Their palaces and their kingdoms were referred to as heavenly places.  This is the same reference meant in Eph. 3:10 because it was God who raised them up,  and allowed them their power and rule. Their earthly dominion was their heaven.  See Ex. 9:16; Judges 2:16, 18; 2 Sam. 23:1; Is. 41:2, 25; Is. 45:13; Jer. 51:11, etc.  (3) (4)

The book of Colossians was written approx. 62 AD.  Therefore, as Paul stated that the gospel had been preached throughout the world of the Roman empire by 62 AD, then the end of the desolations of Jerusalem and the last days was shortly to come to pass(Rev. 1:1). This was the reference back to Dan. 12:6.

> *"...How long shall it be to the end of these wonders?"*  (KJV)

The answer was in the very next verse.

> *"... that it shall be for a time, times, and an half; and when he shall have accomplished **to scatter the power of the holy people,** all these things shall be finished."*  (Dan. 12:7, KJV)

This the end of the 490 days which Gabriel told Daniel in 9:24 would be the end of the desolations of Jerusalem.  The word desolations means complete destruction.  The end was never speaking of the end of all life on earth, nor the end of all time.  It was the end of that old animal sacrificial temple of the Mosaic covenant in Jerusalem.  When the power of the holy people... the power of the Jews in Jerusalem... the power of the Sanhedrin's tyranny over the saints was scattered - that was the end.

That end occurred when that temple in Jerusalem was destroyed in the Roman-Jewish wars of AD 70.  The wars began approx. Feb 67 AD, and ended with the seige of Jerusalem that lasted 5 months (Rev. 9:5, 10) until Sept AD 70.  The last half of the last 70th week was 3-1/2 years of the destruction of Jerusalem.

The interval of the 40 years on an inclusive count between the cutting off of the Messiah in AD 31, and which 40 years was the anti-type of the Exodus 40 years in the wilderness before they entered the earthly promised land.  The anti-type of the end of the Mosaic covenant release from sin and death of the law was the entrance into the spiritual promised land of the new covenant under the gospel of Christ at the full establishment of His kingdom once that old temple was destroyed in AD 70.  (5)

So, we are not living in the last days.  They were.  The last days occurred when Christ walked on this earth.  The last days were "this generation" in which He spoke to His disciples and told them that "all things" would occur in that generation (Matt. 24:34)  It is not "this generation" when we are reading those words 2,000 years later.

> *"For all the prophets and the law prophesied until John."* (Matt. 11:13, KJV)
>
> *"Who verily was foreordained before the foundation of the world, **but was manifest in these last times for you,"***  (1 Pet. 1:20, KJV)

Christ was manifested in the last times, and we know He was manifested in the 1st century AD, therefore the last days were in the first century AD.  We must read these scriptures from the perspective of those people of that century as those were the last times. (6)

Those 3-1/2 years happened a long time ago.  Those days of the Mosaic covenant were the "passing away" of which all of the book of Hebrews spoke.  When they said "the age to come" they were still looking forward into their future to the destruction of that temple (Matt. 24) which had not yet happened for them.

The age to come for them, is now our age... the Messianic age of His everlasting kingdom which we are living in, and which has no end (Isa. 45:17; Eph. 3:21). (7)

Notes:

1) The Signs of Revelation- Part I: The Time of His Coming - [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/02/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-i-the-time-of-his-coming/)

2) Frequent Mistakes - Part IV: Where Was All the World? - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/02/01/frequent-mistakes-part-iv-where-was-all-the-world/)

3) Heaven & Earth Have Passed Away - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/08/26/heaven-earth-have-passed-away/)

4) Revelation: The Four Corners of The Earth - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/05/29/revelation-the-four-corners-of-the-earth/)

5) The Promised Land: Between the Cross and the Kingdom - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/07/13/the-promised-land-between-the-cross-and-the-kingdom/)

6) It's Not The End of The World - Part I - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/18/hello-world/)

7) Frequent Mistakes - Part VI: THe End of The World, or? - [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/04/28/frequent-mistakes-part-vi-the-end-of-the-world-or/)

Answer (score 0):

This phrase (‘time, times and half a time’) comes from the book of Daniel (Daniel 7:25, 12:7) and the book of Revelation (12:14) where it is linked to 1260 days (Revelation 12:6).

Through Daniel 12:11 ‘time, times and half a time’ is associated with a period of 1290 days, where sacrifices are stopped and the time ‘abomination of desolation’ is set up. This seems to be a clear reference to Antiochus Epiphanes IV and yet Jesus points to the end times when this would happen in Matt 24. It seems therefore that the ‘abomination of desolation’ refers to tyrants, agents of Satan’s evil cause and thus ties into different periods of ‘time, times and half a time’ of evil rampage.

However the year is calculated (365.25 days or the more prophetic 360 days) it is usually linked with the short period of 3 ½ years.

[‘time, times and half a time’](https://d2d7ddb1-2fd9-4bd9-80c4-fdf71cc5a593.filesusr.com/ugd/e29720_1c7f229bee254b71a87d14a8efededbd.pdf) is linked to many periods throughout history that are comparable, these are times of tribulation where there is judgment and justice is served. The bible informs or directs us to these times:

- 525-521 BC - Cambyses (son of Cyrus, before the Second Temple is
  built)
- 476-472 BC – Haman (adversary to Esther)
- 168-164 BC –Antiochus Epiphanes IV
- 29-33 AD – Jesus (the Light of the world)
  against the dark enemy
- 67-71 AD – Titus (destroyed to the temple and took away the Menora, the light/authority by which the Jews administered justice)

So I concur that 'times' is double of 'time'.

**1260 years**

The ‘time, times and half a time’ in Revelation 12:6 uses the prophetic 1260 days, where it is 1260 years (3 ½ x 360). This type of prophetic conversion from days to years is justified by:

> I have assigned you the same number of days as the years of their sin.
> So, for 390 days you will bear the sin of the people of Israel. After
> you have finished this, lie down again, this time on your right side,
> and bear the sin of the people of Judah. I have assigned you 40 days,
> a day for each year. Ezekiel 4:5-6

***It is a literal 1260 years*** where the devil deceived the nations:

> The great dragon was hurled down—that ancient serpent called the
> devil, or Satan, who leads the whole world astray. Revelation 12:9

**1000 years**

[The number one thousand (1000) symbolizes “immensity,” “fullness of quantity” or “multitude.”](http://www.scripturerevealed.com/bible-studies/the-meaning-of-numbers-the-number-1000/)

This I believe is where have made the biggest mistake has been made: ***it is not a literal 1000 years (e.g. a Millennium)***. We are to wait until the full number of the Gentiles have come in (Romans 11:25).

> And I saw an angel coming down out of heaven, having the key to the
> Abyss and holding in his hand a great chain. He seized the dragon,
> that ancient serpent, who is the devil, or Satan, and bound him for a
> thousand years. He threw him into the Abyss, and locked and sealed it
> over him, ***to keep him from deceiving the nations anymore until the***
> ***thousand years were ended***. After that, he must be set free for a short
> time. Revelation 20:1-3

In this scenario, when the 1260 years is over when Satan had deceived the nations, something momentous happened that put Satan in the Abyss for ‘1000 years’ – with life in heaven and Christians reigning in the life of Christ down on earth. Note, even though Satan was put in the Abyss his angels are still on earth (Rev 12:9), and the deceived nations are quite capable to continuing being misled without other input.

Satan will be released from the Abyss when the contention between good and evil culminates. And Jesus will return at an undisclosed time.

**So how have I split the time up:**

257 AD – 1517 AD = 1260 years, the dark ages until the doctrine of grace established by Martin Luther. This is followed by the ‘1000 years’ that we are in now. 1517 AD marked a time of ‘awakening’ and more and more revivals have sprung up.

Light and justice are key themes. Consider Jesus is the Light of the World, that the Menora taken from the Jewish Temple, the threat to remove lampstands from churches of the book of Revelation and the light of revelation of the doctrine of grace to Martin Luther.

There is more to this can be written here so please have a look [here](https://math777.wixsite.com/divisionsofhistory/the-return).